# why are my walker menu is showing like this?

Tags: menus, walker

```
<?php
/**
 * The  second Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ) ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php wp_body_open(); ?>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">


        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">


        <div id="navbar2" class="navbar2">


  <div class="navigation-wrap" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">


                    <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></button>
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
                    <?php if ( 'container' == $container ) : ?>
            <div class="container">
        <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="row flex-it">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <?php  
wp_nav_menu(array(  
  'menu' => 'menu-left', 
  'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
  'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker()
)); 
?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 logo-col">
                        <h1><img src= ” header.png” border = 0 alt=”MySite” /></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?php  
wp_nav_menu(array(  
  'menu' => 'menu-right', 
  'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
  'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker()
)); 
?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php   class CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker extends Walker {

  var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';        
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
      unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }
                }

                ?>


                    <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

  <div class="header-wrap" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>



                        <?php $sec_title = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'sec_title', true );
$second_editor = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'second_editor', true);  ?>
<?php $all_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());?>
<h2> <?php echo "".$sec_title;?> </h2>
<p> <?php echo "<br>".$second_editor; ?> </p>
<?php $drop_down = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'drop_down', true );?>
<h2> <?php echo "".$drop_down;?> </h2>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->






        </header><!-- #masthead -->

        <div id="main" class="site-main">
```

[image]

How can i make it show like this ?

[image]

Comment: The walker just controls the HTML. You'll still need to use CSS to style it and lay it out.

Comment: can u tell me how please ?

Comment: I can't teach you CSS here. It's too big a topic, and off-topic at that. There's thousands of resources available for learning CSS.